# Create Nuget package with framework target for win8 app and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, nuget

I'm trying to prepare a NuGet package for targeting x64 Win8 Store Apps. Requirements are to work on Visual Studio 2013 which supports so far (and to my knowledge) NuGet 2.8.6.
So I have a .nuspec file like this:

```
<files>
    <file src="lib\netcore45\wwapi.dll" target="lib\netcore45\wwapi.dll" />
    <file src="lib\netcore45\wwapi.winmd" target="lib\netcore45\wwapi.winmd" />
    <file src="lib\portable-wpa81\wwapi.dll" target="lib\portable-wpa81\wwapi.dll" />
    <file src="lib\portable-wpa81\wwapi.winmd" target="lib\portable-wpa81\wwapi.winmd" />
    <file src="runtimes\win8-x64\native\wwapi.dll" target="runtimes\win8-x64\native\wwapi.dll" />
    <file src="runtimes\win8-x64\native\wwapi.winmd" target="runtimes\win8-x64\native\wwapi.winmd" />
</files>
```

And I used `References` element like this:

```
<references>
        <group targetFramework=".NETCore4.5">
            <reference file="wwapi.winmd" />
        </group>
        <group targetFramework="portable-wpa81">
            <reference file="wwapi.winmd" />
        </group>
</references>
```

However the libraries located under `runtimes` folder do not get added to the x64-targeted project I'm using and therefore it doesn't build. Is there a way to achieve this using following configuration:

1. Visual Studio 2013;
2. Nuget 2.8.6;
3. NuGet Target Framework Monikers;

I'm aware of using PowerShell scripts or having different packages for x86 and x64 but I'm looking for a solution similar to the NuGet 3.0 and Win10 UAP.

Comment: The runtimes folder is not supported by NuGet 2 - http://docs.nuget.org/create/uwp-create

Comment: Yes, I know that. Also [here](http://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.8.6) says that it support framework moniker for win10. Is it only win10?

Comment: They added a uap target framework moniker. NuGet has supported the win target framework moniker before version 2.8.6.

Comment: Is there, somewhere, any example or docs for nuget framework moniker before 2.8.6 and for projects which are not UAP?

Comment: There is a [list](https://docs.nuget.org/create/enforced-package-conventions) but it is incomplete. It does not show any of the Xamarin frameworks, nor uap. The [source code](https://github.com/mrward/nuget/blob/2.8.7/src/Core/Utility/VersionUtility.cs#L57-L130) is where I normally look for the most up to date list of target frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the build folder to achieve automatic selection of x86/x64 versions of a library for W8. This is supported in VS2013, since was added in Nuget 2.5 (see [Nuget 2.5 release notes](https://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.5): Automatic import of msbuild targets and props files)

Basically the solution consists in adding a file at build/.targets having the references to the correct dlls.

Here are some useful links with examples: [link1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mim/archive/2013/09/02/packaging-a-windows-store-apps-component-with-nuget-part-2.aspx) and [link2](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Creating-a-Windows-Store-App-NuGet-Package-for-ARM-x86-and-x64.aspx)